# $P(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n−1}+\dots+a_n$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. If $a_1^2<a_2$ prove that $P(x)$ has no real roots.

Tags: polynomials, roots

> $P(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n−1}+\dots+a_n$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. If $a_1^2<a_2$ prove that $P(x)$ has no real roots.

I tried solving it with contradiction assuming real roots and working out coefficients $a_1$ and $a_2$ but nothing seems to work. I tried using calculus too differentiating it n-2 times but I couldn't find any substantial result.

Comment: You can assume there are $n$ complex roots $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. There are formulas for $a_1$ and $a_2$ in terms of $x_i$'s, do you know them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a real polynomial $x^n+ a_1x^{n-1}+ \cdots a_n$ cannot be completely resolved into linear factors if $a_1^2<a_2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313216/prove-that-a-real-polynomial-xn-a-1xn-1-cdots-a-n-cannot-be-completely)

Answer (score 2):

We may suppose that $a_n\not =0$. Suppose that $P$ has all its roots real. Then it is the same for $Q(x)=x^nP(1/x)=1+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+\cdots$. Put $Q(x)=\prod (x-b_k)$ with $b_k\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $$\frac{Q^{\prime}(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x-b_k},$$ and taking the derivative we get  $$\frac{Q(x)Q^{\prime\prime}(x)-Q^{\prime}(x)^2}{Q(x)^2}=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(x-b_k)^2}$$
Now, putting $x=0$:
$$2a_2-a_1^2=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{b_k^2} $$
and it is easy to finish.

Comment: What was the motivation for this approach , i would not have foreseen from earlier that differentiating that stuff can give that a1 ,a2 terms like we want ?